# watch rootscope on other pages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i want to watch the value of $rootScope in other controllers when ever it is changed

scenario:
on location change when response is sent rootScope variable has value false, when response is got it is true so i want to listen the value of rootscope  on other controllers:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
     $rootScope.loadDisp = false;//listen to this
        AuthenticationService.Login(function (_data) {
            $rootScope.loadDisp = true;//listen to this 
})
```

**subcontroller.js**

```
angular.module('acf')
    .controller('homeController', function _ctrl($scope $rootScope) {

     $scope.$watch('$rootScope.loadDisp', function(newValue, oldValue) {
         console.log('*********8888')
            ctrl.pageView = $rootScope.loadDisp;
            console.log(ctrl.pageView)//only runs first time not second time
        });
```

Comment: I think you need a service to store that variable and `$broadcast` an event when the value changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are listening(watch) the wrong event.

```
$rootScope.$watch('loadDisp', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('*********8888')
    ctrl.pageView = $rootScope.loadDisp;
    console.log(ctrl.pageView) //only runs first time not second time
});
```